# Jenkins ArtifactDeployer plugin - How to specify a local directory as remote directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use the ArtifactDeployer plugin to copy artifacts from the JENKINS_HOME/jobs/ directory into a directory on the same machine which isn't under JENKINS_HOME. I am not sure how to use the Remote Directory parameter to specify the directory on the local machine. Here is a screenshot of how I am trying to specify the local directory.

[image]

I get the following errors:

```
[ArtifactDeployer] - [ERROR] - Failed to deploy. Can't create the directory '\\localhost\usr\local\scm_repo\cbo\artifacts\'
[ArtifactDeployer] - [ERROR] - Failed to mkdirs: \\localhost\usr\local\scm_repo\cbo\artifacts\
```

I couldn't find any documentatin on this too. Any help would be appreciated (even if that means I can use another plugin).

Answer (score 5):

I just figured it out. All you have to do is specify the directory location where you have to deploy your artifact to without the machine details. For example,

```
/usr/local/scm_repo/cbo/artifacts/
```

will actually deploy the artifact in the same machine. Also, use the "Flatten" check box option to not retain the source directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying it to a local machine within a particular directory structure, why not just copy the artifacts using shell.
maybe something like 
`cp ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/wokspace/<path_to_directory_in_which_artifacts_are_stored> <path to repository>`

Perhaps this should help:)

Comment: I could write a shell script. But wanted to make sure if the ArtifactDeployer plugin will work. Also, if there are any other plugin s to do such thing, it will be a much cleaner solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anand, did you try giving the ip of your machine instead of localhost?

Comment: San7888 - I tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and it didn't work. It looks like this plugin can only be used for copying it into remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

ArtifactDeployer plugin enables you to deploy build artifacts from workspace to a remote shared location through the file protocol.
Give only a shared location such as '/nfs/build/repo'.